# How to create internationalized google app engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, internationalization

I am new to google app engine, I want to create a google app engine application.
I am following this [blog](http://blog.yjl.im/2009/02/using-django-i18n-in-google-app-engine.html).

I am trying it with step by step. I am stuck with its 2nd step, where I have created conf package and relatively settings.py. I am getting `ImportError: No module named django.conf` error. What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the link you read is old and may out of date.
The following document may help you config your django on newest app engine python environment.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django?hl=zh-tw

you may need add the following lines in your app.yaml first and see if it solve the ImportError

```
libraries:
- name: django
  version: "1.4"
```